# reduxjs - tracking on redundant data in normalizing state shape

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Normalizing data in redux is common, but what the best way to handle this case.

**Let's say that is the state shape:**

```
{
  booksList: {
      1: { ... },
      2: { ... },
      3: { ... },
      4: { ... },
      5: { ... }
    }
  coolBooks:  [5, 2, 1],
  hotBooks: [1, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Now, application throw action to remove book with id 5 from coolBooks Array, no problem easy!. But in case application throw action to remove book with id 2 from coolBooks list? do I need also to remove from booksList? because it not in use anymore.

1. if you think I don't need to remove data from bookList, don't care and cache unnecessary. **so what with memory leak**? in this example is only 5 books. but in my application it could be thousand entities in booksList if i will not remove unnecessary books.
2. if you think I need to remove the entity from booksList if book is not exist both in coolBooks/hotBooks. what is the best practice? in my application it not only 2 categories(coolBooks/hotBooks) is can be 100. so for each remove operation check for 100 arrays this book is not exist? **what about performance**?

Comment: It's difficult to have a cookie cutter solution because like you say `booksList` might become very large, but what if you can re-add books to `coolBooks`? It's very dependent on your particular use case.

Comment: I agree with your argument, but as I mention booksList might become very large if i not clear unnecessary books, but I add the condition that might be hundred categories( ex. coolBooks/hotBooks). so what is more recommend in this case? and maybe some one know for common solution.

Comment: Let react component construct the coolbooks from the list of books and remove from redux list of books. React will update the data on list of books changes.

Comment: Remove from one place, and don’t worry about the view updates, let the coolbooks be in the component state will avoid you from multiple array operations as react knows how to update and check for state changes. Avoiding complex data structure in redux reducers in this case will split the logic and gives you lower operation costs.

Comment: So if you have 1000 books and 100 lists with 11 books in each, my laptop can scan those lists to see if a book exists about 500,000 times per second.  With 51 books in each of the 100 lists that drops to 130,000 times per second.  If you're really worried, make the lists as objects instead of arrays.  Then with 10,000 books and 1,000 lists with 251 books in each list my laptop can still do about 34,000 scans per second

Comment: You could also store the lists the books are in with the books, or in a new array just for those lists, or with a count for the number of lists the book is in.  Then when you remove you have to remove it in two places, but you can tell when the book is no longer in a list.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat good answer thanks!, i thought too, create object that represent the count for each book is in use(in lists), It seems like there is no particular solution, or some known good practice.